# How do I write a SQL query for an attribute in a table containing only part of a word in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following is the script for my table:

```
create table PRODUCTS
(ProdID   integer      Not null,
 Descrip  varchar(50)  Not null,
     Price    decimal(4,2),
     Primary key(ProdID));


insert into PRODUCTS values (100860,'ace tennis racket I',65.00);
insert into PRODUCTS values (100861,'ace tennis racket II',58.00);
insert into PRODUCTS values (100870,'ace tennis balls-3 pack',15.80);
insert into PRODUCTS values (100871,'ace tennis balls-6 pack',10.00);
insert into PRODUCTS values (100890,'ace tennis net',74.00);
insert into PRODUCTS values (101860,'sp tennis racket',37.00);
insert into PRODUCTS values (101863,'sp junior racket',25.00);
insert into PRODUCTS values (102130,'rh: "guide to tennis"',8.95);
insert into PRODUCTS values (200376,'sb energy bar-6 pack',7.00);
insert into PRODUCTS values (200380,'sb vita snack-6 pack',8.40);
```

How do I write the select script where the description has "racket" and I don't have to fully enter "ace tennis racket I", "ace tennis racket II" or "junior racket" to get all the rackets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just use the

```
select * from PRODUCTS where Descrip LIKE '%racket%'
```

you can look into SQL pattern matching here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: thank you.  I cant up vote because I don't have 15 reputation yet

Answer (score 0):

```
    select * from Products where INSTR(Descrip, 'racket') > 0;
```

Comment: While this might work, using functions in the where clause tends to slow down production.